# Tilestream support in Route-me

Tags: ios, mapping, route-me

Has anyone been able to integrate the opensource TileStream server with the route-me framework for iOS? The documentation is pretty scarce. I have been able initialize a dictionary with the data for my map, however I get a sigabrt whenever I try and run the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a sample project showing how this works:

https://github.com/mapbox/tilestream-ios-example